# Можно ли непроизводные слова делить на морфемы?

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор

В русском языке много непроизводных слов. В одних случаях современные носители языка   могут свободно определить составляющие их морфемы, в других - это делается с трудом, в третьих - требуется этимологический анализ. А можем ли мы вообще выделять отдельные морфемы в непроизводных словах и где грань, позволяющая это сделать?

P.S. Решила собирать ссылки, без них здесь никуда (смайлик). Хорошо бы ссылочку от самого Лопатина, да из академической грамматики.

ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНО.

В  ссылках излагается ФОРМАЛЬНО-ГРАММАТИЧЕСКАЯ теория членения слова на морфемы. Основной вопрос - это определение вида основы: производная, делимая на морфемы, или непроизводная. Приведенные там примеры воспринимаются как  ОДНОЗНАЧНО решаемые, а все СПОРНЫЕ И ПОГРАНИЧНЫЕ обходятся стороной. И не получилось  найти ответ на главный вопрос:  должна ли  производная основа только СООТНОСИТЬСЯ с непроизводной основой или она должна ОБРАЗОВЫВАТЬСЯ от нее. И какая СООТНЕСЕННОСТЬ имеется в виду: точная по значению или примерно подходящая?

Вот, например, слово «ПОХОД». В толковом словаре Ожегова: походить – это ходить некоторое время, то есть предлог имеет временное (ненаправленное ) значение: походить с полчаса, часы походили и встали. А вот «поход» там определяется как передвижение с определенной целью: туристический поход, военный поход, дальняя прогулка с определенной целью. Здесь приставка ПО имеет направленное (целевое) значение.

А  «простой» Тихонов  на такие мелочи  внимания не обращает, у него: походить →  поход, основа производная, делим на части. И ничего, что многозначная приставка ПО сюда несколько не подходит, зато думать не надо. И вот так, шаг за шагом, отступает семантическая орфография, основы который были заложены еще Ломоносовым.

ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНО.
Благодарю Вас за ссылки, обязательно с ними ознакомлюсь, так как для меня этот вопрос остается открытым. И еще по поводу  суффиксального "воробья": кажется, словообразование часто сопровождается усечением основы, но усеченную часть странно было бы считать суффиксом.

Comment: София, развейте мои сомнения)  
Вы действительно считаете слово **поход** непроизводным?? Давайте откроем словарь 1847 : "**ходъ** - шествие, движение" ......... "**походъ** - шествие войск из страны в страну, или из одного места в другое". То есть поступательное движение отряда людей по заранее намеченному маршруту. Проще пареной репы, согласитесь! И почему это "простой" Тихонов не пошел по этому пути)

Answer (score 1):

Слово или основа?

Непроизводная основа обычно включает только корень, хотя иногда непроизводная основа может включать, помимо корня, суффикс, реже – префикс.
Брат□, ночь□, стен-а, окн-о.
Например, основа глагола читать (чита-) включает корень чит- и глагольный суффикс -а-. Но данное слово не образовано ни от какого другого однокоренного слова. Поэтому слово и его основа являются непроизводными. 
http://www.licey.net/russian/phonetics/2_10

Хотите - разбирайтесь: Дальше даются другие определения непроизводной основы .Но точную грань деления вряд ли найдёте. У всех разные представления, а Лопатин со своими дериватами мне и вовсе непонятен.

http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs/index-128719.html?page=6

Непроизводные основы – это основы, в составе которых не выделяются живые аффиксы. Живой аффикс – это морф, значение которого определяется с позиций синхронного словообразования. Непроизводная основа называет предметы и явления немотивированно, непосредственно: дом, комнат-а, бел-ый. Непроизводная основа является нечленимой и состоит только из корня.
 http://www.lingvotech.com/osnova

http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-045.htm

Непроизводная основа (немотивированная) - это единое целое, неразложимое на отдельные морфемы (значащие части);   производная основа (мотивированная) - составное единство, членимое на отдельные морфемы.
Членимость производной основы на значащие части является морфологической особенностью этой основы и отличает ее от непроизводной.

Comment: Видимо, каждое слово нужно рассматривать отдельно - с точки зрения современного значения.Вот ЗОНТИК - так пришёл в наш язык,с неразложимой основой, в русском языке появился зонт, а зонтик стал восприниматься как маленький зонт, произошло переразложение основы, она стала делимой.

Comment: Если вопрос ещё актуален, вот ещё курсовая, там есть и ссылочки на теорию.    http://otherreferats.allbest.ru/languages/00181671_0.html - о связанных корнях и непроизводной основе.

Comment: Кстати, воробей - сейчас воспринимается как непроизводное, а вычленяются корень+ суфф. вороб/ей и говорят СВЯЗАННЫЙ корень, а вычленяется он при сопоставлении с однокоренными воробьиха, воробышек, воробьиный. Когда-то мотивировался звукоподражанием, теперь нет. А некоторые не согласны и говорят, что это весь корень. Так что грань - у нас в мозгах и в словарях.